# What's the word for “busting the myth”?

Tags: phrases, expressions

Suppose, I want to say that you need to bust the myth that girls are not good at sports  or any other stereotype for that matter.

What's the word to prove wrong an old, established stereotype?

Is it correct to say 'break the stereotype' or 'break the cliche'?

Comment: I think "break the stereotype" is fine.  "Break the cliche" doesn't sound quite right.  "Shatter the myth" is a common phrase for this, when it's done with a single strong stroke.

Comment: @Hot Licks, Ok Thanks,If I want to use the word cliche then what's the correct phrase?

Comment: @QualityTalk As a dictionary will tell you, a *cliché* is a phrase or metaphor that has become trite from overuse (e.g. *avoid clichés like the plague*); it is orthagonal to stereotype. What is the cliché you want to counter or contrast? Do you just want to point out something is contrary to an adage or breaks with conventional wisdom?

Comment: @choster Though [they used to mean the same thing](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotype_(printing)).

Comment: **Demystify**...

Comment: I would probably understand “break the cliché” in a literal way: someone accidentally dropped the printing stereoplate on the floor, and it broke into pieces.

Answer (score 99):

You could consider "[debunk](http://www.encyclopedia.com/doc/1O999-debunk.html)"

> To expose the falseness or hollowness of (a myth, idea, or belief).

Individual cases where a stereotypical assumption is confounded might be described as someone "breaking the mold"

[Women Artists Who Broke the Mold](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/janice-sands/women-artists-who-broke-t_b_5049472.html)

Comment: I think that's appropriate when you do so in a scientific way, but it sounds like the OP is considering more the actions of an individual.  (Such as a girl succeeding at sports.)  In that sort of context "debunk" would be a little odd.

Comment: @starwed proving wrong by being a counter example to the myth? Yes see what you mean. Will have a think.

Comment: Good suggestion but there are a load of synonyms - *puncture, confute, quash, discredit, disprove, controvert, invalidate, negate etc*

Comment: I somehow do not like the use of the word "confound". I think "confront" is a better word here.

Comment: @Jonas - Why? ["prove (a theory or expectation) wrong."](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/confound) seems to fit.

Comment: "Breaking the fold" does not seem to me involve proving something is wrong. To me it is a step taken that confirms a person's desire to challenge the social norm.

Answer (score 22):

*Debunk* is spot on but, if you don't mind being a little less accurate, *dispel* also works and I've seen it in this context quite frequently.

> I am posting this in order to dispel the myths and rumours that answers posted three hours after the question never get upvotes.

Answer (score 17):

[*Disprove*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disprove) means "to show that (something) is false or wrong." So you could say, for example, "A recent study **disproves** the myth that girls are bad at sports."

Answer (score 6):

I think it's OK with break the stereotype.
I suggest also **demolish**, **get rid of**, **eliminate** the stereotype, and **explode**, **shatter**, **ruin** the myth.

Comment: Demolish and shatter are particularly appropriate when the person shows great excellence

Comment: Depends on the audience but in non sensational writing, myths (which by their definition are not true) need to be supported, to do otherwise looks loaded. jmoreno mentions that some terms are accurate in individual cases, to show differentiation from the group but that has the opposite intent from what the author probably wants because it reinforces the stereotype, by illustrating an exception rather than a rule. The above terms are certainly fine but very careful argument construction would be needed to not fall subject to previously mentioned issues.

Answer (score 4):

A more colorful phrase to describe your situation is that someone is **putting the lie to** a myth or cliche. This is usually used to describe something which belies some usually-overreaching claim or statement, and has a somewhat triumphant air of "Ah-hah! I have found a clear counterexample to this absurd statement!"

As an example, from last month's Washington Post:

> Five myths about lame-duck presidents
>
> 1. Lame-duck presidents cannot get anything done.
>
> Wartime presidents as diverse as Franklin D. Roosevelt, Ronald Reagan and George W. Bush
>   put the lie to this myth.

Also, http://www.thefreedictionary.com/put+the+lie+to

Comment: What's a "lame-duck president"?

Comment: A president with no more elections ahead of them.  Since US presidents typically participate in their midterm elections (even though they themselves are not on the ballot), in the US this phrase is intended to indicate the final two years of a president's last term in office.

Answer (score 4):

Mythbusting

Only nerds will understand this reference to the TV show Mythbusters, but this could be suitable depending on your audience.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythBusters

Comment: Only nerds? I'm pretty sure that show is aimed a general (ie: not highly educated) audience. It would be more accurate to say "only TV watchers".

Comment: @slicedtoad being a nerd has nothing to do with education by my definition.

Comment: @slicedtoad He could go into great detail about exactly what sort of person would understand the reference (which includes many people who do not watch TV, but not people that watch only other types of TV), but I don't think that such specificity is necessary here.

Comment: @Saposhiente Right. But my issue isn't with specificity, it's with accuracy. He says "Only nerds will understand this reference". From my experience (possible localization bias), nerds would be *less likely* to watch this type of TV than, say, your average car mechanic. Granted the definition of nerd is rather broad and can be vastly different between individuals (even in a given locale). Also, I'm pulling from my experience, not any solid stats. So I'm not pushing it, just mentioning it as a "worth noting".

Comment: @slicedtoad the miscommunication is in the definition of nerd. In my definition, a mechanic, or any other profession/education can be a nerd

Answer (score 4):

*to refute a myth*

> *to refute*:
>
> Prove (a statement or theory) to be wrong or false; disprove.

[OxfordDictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/refute?searchDictCode=all)

[A simple google search](https://www.google.lt/?gws_rd=ssl#q=to+refute+a+myth) shows that *to refute a myth* is indeed actually used widely enough.

It is also used in books, as seen in this [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=refute+a+myth%2C+debunk+a+myth&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crefute%20a%20myth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdebunk%20a%20myth%3B%2Cc0) (which also shows how the phrase compares with the more popular *to debunk a myth*).

Answer (score 1):

You can [*puncture*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/puncture) a myth or stereotype:

> VERB
>
> 2 Cause a sudden collapse of (mood or feeling):
>
> EXAMPLE SENTENCES
>
> *the earlier mood of optimism was punctured*
>
> *The company has punctured this fragile mood of optimism with a miscalculation of astonishing proportions.*
>
> *Worse still is the title track - eight-and-a-half minutes of tedium and cliché interrupted by bad Riverdance impressions which really puncture the dark mood the song is trying to conjure up.*
>
> ***Sigmund Freud's theories have been punctured** and pricked with doubt, but anyone who argues that he should be dropped from the canon of Western civilization needs therapy.*

(Definition and examples from Oxforddictionaries.com)

Answer (score 1):

Disabuse - to show or convince someone that a belief is incorrect

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disabuse

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/disabuse

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add an answer to the several good ones here to point out a slight distinction between the title and body of your question.

It's fairly common parlance to refer to *stereotypes* as *myths*, but there are certainly many *myths* which are certainly not *stereotypes*.

Consider the *myth*, or *old wives' tale* that:

> Toast always lands buttered side down!

This would never be described as a 'toast stereotype', but it would be a myth. You could *debunk*, *bust*, or *shed light on* this myth - simply by dropping toast and watching it land buttered side up.

Next consider the *stereotype*, or at a stretch *myth* that:

> Blonde-haired women are dumb.

A blonde-haired woman could *break the stereotype*, *break the mold*, *prove herself*, *disprove the stereotype*, by doing something intelligent I suppose.

A cliché is different again, and really doesn't fit at all here. I might use the cliché:

> He's as old as the hills!

to describe someone, but *he* wouldn't really be busting a myth - and certainly not breaking a stereotype  - in producing a birth certificate that proved himself younger than the hills.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'puncturing' and 'busting,' I would rather prefer 'sabotaging' and this word will give the correct meaning in this industrial age.